# Sankey Diagram Nodes numeration d3 js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, sankey-diagram

[image]

I'm working on this code, and there are problems that I'm aint able to find it out, the point is I am not able to get them as i want :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sankey</title>
<style>

.node rect {
 cursor: move;
 fill-opacity: .9;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.node text {
 pointer-events: none;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
 }

.link {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
stroke-opacity: .2;
}

.link:hover {
 stroke-opacity: .5;
}


  </style>

  <body>


 <p id="chart">


 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js">   </script>


<script src="sankey.js"></script>






<script>

var margin = {top: 50, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 1800- margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 480 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) ; },
color = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var sankey = d3.sankey()
.nodeWidth(35) //changes width of node
.nodePadding(10)
.size([width, height]);



function loadCSV(file) {
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {

    request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
// load
request.open('GET', file, false);
request.send();
parseCSV(request.responseText);
return file=request.responseText;
}


function parseCSV(data){
//alert(data);
}

var ccs=loadCSV("sankey.csv");

console.log(ccs);


var json = ccs.split('\n').reduce(function(result, line, index) {
  if (index > 0) { // Skip header.
var data = line.split(',');
console.log (data);
if (data.length === 5) { // Skip rows with incomplete columns.
  var containsSourceNode = result.nodes.some(function(node) { return node.name === data[0]; });
  if (!containsSourceNode) {
    result.nodes.push({
      node : result.nodes.length,
      name : data[0],
      xPos : data[1]
    });
  }

  var containsTargetNode = result.nodes.some(function(node) { return node.name === data[2]; });
  if (!containsTargetNode) {
    result.nodes.push({
      node : result.nodes.length,
      name : data[2],
      xPos : data[3]
    });
  }

     result.links.push({
     source : result.nodes.filter(function(node) { return node.name ===   data[0]; })[0].node,
      target : result.nodes.filter(function(node) { return node.name === data[2]; })[0].node,
    value : data[4[![\]
    ][1]][1]});
   }
  }
 console.log(result);
 return result;
 }, {
 nodes : [],
 links : []
 });


var path = sankey.link();
var renderSankey = function(d) {
  window.width = 280; //determines the width of the dra
  sankey
  .nodes(d.nodes)  
  .links(d.links)
  .layout(32);





var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
  .data(d.links)
 .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

   link.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" +     format(d.value); });

 var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
      .data(d.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y +     ")"; })
.call(d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) { return d; })
  .on("dragstart", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
  .on("drag", dragmove));


  console.log(node);
  node.append("rect")
  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
  .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

 node.append("text")
  .attr("x", -6)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", null)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
  .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
  .attr("text-anchor", "start");

      function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
    "translate(" + (
         d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - d.dx, d3.event.x))
      ) + "," + (
               d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
        ) + ")");
    sankey.relayout();
    link.attr("d", path);

  }

var extractX = function(d){ return d['x']};
function numOrdA(a, b){ return (a-b); }
var locX = d['nodes'].map(extractX).sort(numOrdA);
var PosX = _.uniq(locX);

 console.log(PosX);

var extractY = function(d){ return d['y']};
var locY = d['nodes'].map(extractY).sort(numOrdA);
var PosY = _.max(locY);


svg.append("text")         
.style("fill", "#225ea8")   
.style("font-weight",400)
.style("font-family","Helvetica Neue")
.attr("x", PosX[0])           
.attr("y", 420)          
.text("test1"); 



svg.append("text")         
 .style("fill", "#225ea8")   
.style("font-weight",400)
.style("font-family","Helvetica Neue")
.attr("x", PosX[1] )          
.attr("y", 420)          
.text("test2"); 


console.log(PosX[1]);

 svg.append("text")        
.style("fill", "#225ea8")  
.style("font-weight",400)
.style("font-family","Helvetica Neue")
.attr("x", PosX[2])           
.attr("y", 420)           
.text("test3"); 





 svg.append("text")        
.style("fill", "#225ea8")  
.style("font-weight",400)
.style("font-family","Helvetica Neue")
.attr("x", PosX[3])           
.attr("y", 420)           
.text("test4"); 



svg.append("text")        
.style("fill", "#225ea8")  
.style("font-weight",400)
.style("font-family","Helvetica Neue")
.attr("x", PosX[4])           
.attr("y", 420)           
.text("test5"); 



}

renderSankey(json);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this script should do visualization from a csv file, and i gotta an example also , it is only an example :

```
source,xPos,target,xPos,value
user1,0,user2,1,4
user2,1,user3,2,4
user1,0,user3,2,2
user1,0,user4,2,2
user6,1,user8,2,2
user_123,3,User1_1,4,2
user12_2,4,user1122,5,3
userab1,2,user122m,5,4
user12_2,4,user122m,5,2
user1,0,user555,5,2
user2,1,User1_1,4,2
userabc,4
```

the visualization doesnt work and maybe there is some code mistakes that i aint able to find.

Comment: Hey Chis it would be helpful if you included an example of the expected behavior along with your current results. You pasted a lot of code, but since you don't even know what errors you're getting it's super difficult for anyone else to help you.

Comment: well at the visualiztion side i mean HTML page the data doesnt look as it should be ,the nodes are not in their right pos. @nick

Comment: OK hm- but that doesn't really mean anything to me. Sure there's something wrong with your code, but I can't see it without an example, and I'm not going to spend 30 minutes trying to replicate your results using the code you've pasted above. If someone is willing to do that, then you're very lucky! 9 out of 10 times though, you won't get any help if you can't narrow down the issue and you can't provide examples of what you've tried and what hasn't worked :)